# Class sharing between byte-buddy interceptors/advices

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to pass monitoring/tracing information through all my external calls in my java application.
To make it transparent, I'm trying to use byte-buddy but have some troubles getting it to work.

To trace every incoming (http) request, I intercept `HttpServlet.service()`, extract the token header from the `HttpServletRequest` and put it in a static `ThreadLocal` in a class named `TokenHolder`.

To trace every outgoing (http) request, I intercept `HttpURLConnection` and add the token header I get from the same `ThreadLocal` (`TokenHolder`).

The problem I have is that `TokenHolder` seems to be initialized twice and my 2 interceptors are not writing-to/reading-from the same `ThreadLocal` and I can't find a way to do it.

I suppose the problem is that `HttpURLConnection` lives in the bootclasspath while the servlet API does not.

Bonus question: is it possible to intercept `URL.openConnection()`? That was my first idea but I never could do it because I suppose the `URL` class is loaded before the agent (because of `URLClassLoader`) but I don't know if there are workarounds to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can register a `RedefinitionStrategy` where Byte Buddy transforms previously loaded classes. To do so, you do however need to avoid adding methods or fields. This can typically be done by using `Advice` only.

You are also right that classes need to live on the bootstrap loader. You can inject classes into the bootstrap loader by placing them in a jar and using the designated method in the `Instrumentation` interface.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to correctly redefine `URL`. I also injected all of my interceptors/advices/auxiliary classes in the boot classpath with `ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(temp, BOOTSTRAP, inst).inject(map)` and `enableBootstrapInjection(inst, temp)` but at runtime (in wildfly), I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for my interceptor (target for method delegation). Am I doing something wrong or do you think wildfly is restricting  what classes may be visible to my application?

Comment: Wildfly probably prevents the class from being visible to your class loader. Try importing the namespace or add your boot classes to a known package such as java.lang.

Comment: It was just a matter of setting the right JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS parameter.